# How can I specify which LLVM binaries GHC should use?

Tags: haskell, compilation, llvm, ghc

I have successfully built [`PortFusion`](//hackage.haskell.org/package/PortFusion) with [the brand new 64-bit GHC 7.6.1 Release Candidate 1 for Windows](//www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2012-August/022671.html).

Using freshly downloaded *native 64-bit* `mingw` binaries from http://www.drangon.org/mingw, the [`network`](//hackage.haskell.org/package/network) package was as easy to install (after a bunch of non-relevant small fixes) as a simple

```
CC=mingw64/bin/gcc cabal install
```

---

There is also an `LLVM` toolchain package on the same website.

Now I wonder how I could tell `GHC` to use specific `LLVM` binaries during compilation.

---

Would it be something as simple and similar to above as:

```
#v??v
 LLVM=????????? ghc -W -O2 -fllvm -optlo-O3 --make src/Main.hs
 LLVM=????????? cabal install PortFusion -f llvm #¹
#^??^
```

*[¹ relevant line in PortFusion.cabal defining the `llvm` flag](//github.com/corsis/PortFusion/blob/1138a4ebb4bc30fdbff4fdd378f3eadc5dce673b/PortFusion.cabal#L100)*

or completely different?

Comment: My understanding is that `ghc` just uses whatever `llc` executable is in path; http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/Preparation/Windows suggests that you would follow the standard unixy instruction of adding export `PATH=${PATH}:/c/dev/llvm/bin` to a .profile file, assuming thats where `llc` ended up.

Comment: @applicative I have tried it with `PATH` but ended up having to file a bug report: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7143.

Comment: Did you get some resolution? I have the same issue using the GHC package under Arch Linux on ARM.

Comment: No, I have not. I would have written an answer otherwise. Please let us know of how things go for you on Linux!

Answer (score 6):

For the record, the answer to the question in the title is

```
ghc -pgmlo opt_cmd -pgmlc llc_cmd -fllvm ...
```

`opt_cmd` and `llc_cmd` can be either command names (that will be looked up in `PATH`) or full pathnames.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to get GHC to use certain binaries by altering where they are defined in the `PATH` environment variable. Earlier takes precedence. Presumably, System `PATH` is also higher precedence than User `PATH`.